# How to check whether GridView is Empty or not in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have add buttons in `GridView` using base adapter, that buttons depend on word length when click the button then hide. After clicking all buttons the `GridView` is make empty i want to check, if `GridView` is Empty Display another buttons. I want to check whether `GridView` is empty or not in `GridViewActivity.java`

Here is the code.

GridViewActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spellword);

        txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtview);
        image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview1);

        map.put("melon", R.drawable.melon);
        image.setImageResource(map.get("melon"));


        gridView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid1);
        gridView.setAdapter(new SpellAdapter(this,words,word));

        detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this, this);

    }
```

SpellAdapter.java

```
public class SpellAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    public Context context;
    public char[] word;

    public SpellAdapter(Context context, char[] word, String orglWord)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.word=word;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        count=word.length;
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }


    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {

        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) 
        {  
             LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             v = vi.inflate(R.layout.buttonlist, null);
        } 

        final Button btn= (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.letterbtn);

        btn.setText(word[position]+"");

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                letters=btn.getText();
                String word = letters.toString();
                btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }


        });

        return v; 
    }




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (gridView.getChildCount() == 0) {...}`

If this doesn't work try:

`if (SpellAdapter.isEmpty()) {...}` Or I think you would need to do something like:

`if (gridView.getAdapter().isEmpty()) {...}`

You can find this info [here](http://developer.android.com/index.html#q=GridView) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)

Edit:

Oh I think I see what you mean now. You just hide the button, you don't remove it. So you will need to use a loop. First, get the number of child count. Then do a for, like:

`for ( int x = 0; x < childcount; x++)`

Inside the for you use `View v = gridView.getChildAt(x);`

Then you do `if (v instanceof Button)` and inside the if you check if the button is visible or not. If it is visible, set false inside a variable like `boolean gridViewEmpty` and break the loop. Else, set gridViewEmpty to true and then display your other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get child count.

```
if(gridView.getChildCount() == 0){
-------
-------
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old but, I would also just like to add to this...

If you are displaying a `GridView` in a fragment or you are adding to the `GridView` in another `Activity` and then returning to that `Activity` you will have to have to check in `OnCreate` and `OnResume`.

The following worked for me:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.studentfragment, null);

    gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    empty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.esc);

    if (gridView.getAdapter().isEmpty()){
        empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return v;
}


@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    if (gridView.getAdapter().isEmpty()){
        empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


}
```

---

**OR** you can just create a method that check if `GridView` is empty and call it in `OnCreate` and `OnResume` like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.studentfragment, null);

    gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    empty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.esc);

    checkIfGridIsEmpty();

    return v;
}


@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    checkIfGridIsEmpty();

}

private void checkIfGridIsEmpty() {

    if (gridView.getAdapter().isEmpty()){
        empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else {
        empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

**If you are only checking in `OnCreate`, then you will have to closed and re-opened the `Activity` in order to see if there was differences made to `Gridview`/`Adapter`.**